# jQuery File Upload plugin asks me to download the file, what is wrong?

Tags: jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload and I was able to upload and save the file to designated folder, and then I return the Json object. Then the browser (I use IE8) pops "File Download" dialog and asks me to download a file named "upload75bea5a4" with no extension. I just could not figure out what is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using the same plugin and it's working without any problems for me. I will post the codes I am using so that can help you. The C# code I saw at [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx) (and I made few changes).

A class to store the properties of the file:

```
public class ViewDataUploadFilesResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The upload code, which is called by the ajax:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string UploadFiles()
    {
        var r = new List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult>();
        Core.Settings settings = new Core.Settings();
        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
            if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
                continue;
            string savedFileName = Path.Combine(settings.StorageLocation + "\\Files\\", Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
            hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);

            r.Add(new ViewDataUploadFilesResult()
            {
                Name = hpf.FileName,
                Length = hpf.ContentLength,
                Type = hpf.ContentType
            });
        }
        return "{\"name\":\"" + r[0].Name + "\",\"type\":\"" + r[0].Type + "\",\"size\":\"" + string.Format("{0} bytes", r[0].Length) + "\"}";
    }
```

The javascript piece which makes the magic:

```
$('#file_upload').fileUploadUI({
    uploadTable: $('#files'),
    downloadTable: $('#files'),
    buildUploadRow: function (files, index) {
        return $('<tr><td>' + files[index].name + '<\/td>' +
                '<td class="file_upload_progress"><div><\/div><\/td>' +
                '<td class="file_upload_cancel">' +
                '<button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="Cancel">' +
                '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-cancel">Cancel<\/span>' +
                '<\/button><\/td><\/tr>');
    },
    buildDownloadRow: function (file) {
        return $('<tr><td>' + file.name + '<\/td><\/tr>');
    }
});
```

Take a look and make some tests.

--

**EDIT**

[I wrote an article about it](http://bit.ly/Npjoz3).

Comment: Thank you so much Davis, I tried it and now I gets an exception in the javascript file "jquery.fileupload-ui.js" line 94 saying there is an unhandled exception. Any ideas?

Comment: There was a **<table id="files"></table>** at that example page. Did you also add it to the page? Without that you either have errors or no file is uploaded at all.

Comment: Yeah, I have that line in there. Did you do anything special to the response content type?

Comment: I have just updated the javascript code. In case you were using that one I have posted you might have this error since I made some small change as I had a very specific case. So, copy it again. I toke from the original source. But actually it's strange you have this error. The only problem I had was bcoz of that table, which I have ignored at the first time. Anyway, as I said, try this new javascript.

Comment: Maybe the form... <form id="file_upload" action="/Post/UploadFiles" method="post" **enctype="multipart/form-data"** >

Comment: I'm able to save the file on the server side.  I still have that error, are you using the file jquery.fileupload-ui.js version 3.6?  Could it be the return string or something else?

Comment: Hum... It seems we are using the same version. I would recommend you to test it with Firefox and Firebug (if you aren't doing so) or IE on debug mode (again, if you aren't doing so) to get the exact error. The return string is just a handmade JSON and I didnt do anything with the content type. My code is just this what you see, but it's strange that I didnt get this error... What jQuery version are you using? 1.5?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.4.4 and jQueryUI 1.8.6 which I copied from the sample on blueimp's github wiki page.  Thank you Davis for helping out, I'll figure it out later.  I've marked yours as answer and upvoted you.

Comment: @DavisSousa, there still is not MVC3 opens source working example of jQuery-File-Upload. I am sure if you were to post an article with a demo project it would be popular.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov, after a looooong time I have wrote an article about it with an sample to download: http://bit.ly/Npjoz3
Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: Davis, three months ago I went ahead and forked a plugin demo to implement it in MVC 3. It is available at GitHub since then https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3

Answer (score 0):

Just found this in the FAQ. See #2
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions

gist is to set content-type to text/plain when HTTP_ACCEPT header does not exists or doesn't contain 'application/json' (inferring iframe on xhr upload).

+1 for D. Sousa's reminder for enctype="multipart/form-data"  - I ran into that as well as the content-type.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For .Net the code for checking the content type in MVC coming back looks like this:

```
if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"] != null && Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"].Contains("application/json"))
{
    return Json(data, "application/json");
}
else
{
    return Json(data, "text/plain");
}
```

Apparently IE does not like `Content-type: text/plain` but `text/plain`.

Hope this saves somebody a further headache.