# Using MVC3, the bluimp jQuery File Upload plugin asks me to download the file?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

Greetings,

I'm using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload (downloaded the version as of 5/21/2011) along with ASP.NET MVC3.

And here are the versions of jquery I am using:

-jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js 
-jquery-1.6.1.js

I was able to upload and save the file to designated folder, and then I return the Json object. Then the IE 7 browser pops a "File Download" dialog and asks me to download a file named "upload75bea5a4" with no extension. 
I also testing in FF 3.6, and it too pops up a "file download" dialog and asks me to download a file named "UploadFiles" (which is the controller action name).
Any idea what's going on here?  Do I need to set the content-type in the header explicitly?

Thanks much in advance.

This is basically the same question posed by Ray in this thread:

[jQuery File Upload plugin asks me to download the file, what is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086189/jquery-file-upload-plugin-asks-me-to-download-the-file-what-is-wrong/6079386#6079386)

No working solution was posed however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to change the content type to `text/plain` as per [this discussion](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/123). 
And here's what they suggest:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection form)
{
    ...
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
    return Content(json, "text/plain");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

download the new version, alterations have been made for this.