# What to return from a controller action for jQuery File Upload plugin?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I'm using the demo page provided with the jQuery File Upload version 5.6 from Blueimp.  I can get the demo working in my ASP.NET MVC project to the point where a file can be uploaded from the page.

However, even though the file successfully gets uploaded, the UI reports an error.  I'm 100% certain this error is because I'm not returning the proper information from my controller action.

Here is my existing action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual JsonResult ImageUpload(FormCollection formdata)
    {
        var imagePath = Setting.Load(SettingKey.BlogImagesBasePath).Value;
        for(var i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var saveFileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", imagePath, Request.Files[i].FileName);
            Log.DebugFormat("Attempting to save file: {0}", saveFileName);
            Request.Files[i].SaveAs(saveFileName);
        }

        return Json(new {});
    }
```

I don't know what the content of the result should be.  I tried sorting through the php example but, not being at all familiar with php, the best I could make of it is that the filename, size, and type might be involved.

Does somebody have a link to a working MVC sample or provide the information I need to return the correct data to the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sailing Judo

I think this question addresses your needs 100%:

[jQuery File Upload plugin asks me to download the file, what is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086189/jquery-file-upload-plugin-asks-me-to-download-the-file-what-is-wrong)

here's basically what it demos:

the class:

```
public class ViewDataUploadFilesResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

the action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFiles()
{
    var r = new List<ViewDataUploadFilesResult>();
    Core.Settings settings = new Core.Settings();
    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
            continue;
        string savedFileName = Path.Combine(settings.StorageLocation + "\\Files\\", Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
        hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);

        r.Add(new ViewDataUploadFilesResult()
        {
            Name = hpf.FileName,
            Length = hpf.ContentLength,
            Type = hpf.ContentType
        });
    }
    return Json(r);
}
```

so, basically, you'd just need to return the jsonresult of the ViewDataUploadFilesResult collection.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it does, thanks.  i searched lots of times on SO but hadn't seen this one.

Comment: sj - i know exactly what you mean, i'm the kind of guy that leaves his glasses on top of his head whilst searching for them :)

Comment: using the above code, I received an error: "Empty file upload result" since the response was not a files[] array.  I found the following in an unrelated sample and modified it, hope this addition helps anyone encountering the same problem: var uploadedFiles = new
            {
                files = r.ToArray()
            };
            return Json(uploadedFiles);

Comment: thanks dillon - feel free to modify my answer to match your version of the plugin with those changes.